# Можно ли употреблять сочетание "В кровати"

Tags: лексика

Говорить "на кровати" не является отклонением от норм русского языка, т.к. чаще всего люди и располагаются "на", то есть "поверх" кровати. Но вот довольно распространённое "в кровати", "в постели". Вызывает сомнение. Значат ли эти сочетания "под одеялом", просторечны ли они?

P.s.: если допустимы они, тогда, выходит, допустимы и "из кровати", "из постели" (на—с, в—из)

Answer (score 1):

Похожий вопрос был на Грамоте:

> Как правильно: прыгать в кровать или прыгать на кровать?
>
> Ответ справочной службы русского языка:
>
> Оба варианта возможны, есть разница в значении: употребление предлога
>   на подчеркивает, что речь идет о поверхности. Ср.: лечь в кровать и
>   уснуть – лечь на кровать в одежде.

http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C

У меня такие же представления, как у Вас.  Когда мы произносим слово кровать, мы представляем себе мебель - длинную раму с ножками и двумя спинками, на которую кладут матрас и постельные принадлежности. Если мы прыгаем на кровать - мы прыгаем на поверхность постельных принадлежностей (если б их не было, было бы уточнение - на матрас, на простынь, на одеяло), если в кровать - видимо, покрывало уже убрано и возможно лечь сразу под одеяло, под плед (внутрь чего-то).

"*Я ещё в кровати*" означает, что говорящий лежит под одеялом, под пледом, среди одеял, в общем, ещё не вышел из комфортной зоны недавнего сна. В этом случае **в кровати** и **в постели** - полные синонимы. "Сейчас встану с кровати" - подчеркивается, что кто-то находился на поверхности кровати, а теперь встаёт с неё. "Встану из кровати" не скажешь, как и "выйду из кровати" - это нелогично, а вот "выполз из постели весь заспанный..." возможно, тогда мы представляем его выползающим из-под одеяла, а не покидающим саму кровать. С кровати всё-таки встают.

Я не вижу здесь никакой просторечности, просто чуть разные оттенки значения.

Answer (score 0):

```
Это он лежит в кровати 
С одеялами на вате,
```

*С. Михалков - "Мимоза"*